# "org.hibernate.TypeMismatchException: Provided id of the wrong type" when using @OneToOne for a bi-directional relation

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa-2.0, type-mismatch

I don't succeed in using @OneToOne when the composite primary key is the same in both classes:

```
@Entity
public class One implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @EmbeddedId
    private OnePK onePK;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "one")
    private Two two;
    //... constructors, getters and setters
}

@Entity
public class Two implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @EmbeddedId
    private TwoPK twoPK;
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "P_ID", referencedColumnName = "P_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false),
        @JoinColumn(name = "L_ID", referencedColumnName = "L_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)})
    @OneToOne(optional = false)
    private One one;
    //... constructors, getters and setters
}

@Embeddable
public class OnePK implements Serializable {
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "P_ID")
    private BigInteger dId;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "L_ID")
    private BigInteger lId;
    //... constructors, getters and setters
}

@Embeddable
public class TwoPK implements Serializable {
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "P_ID")
    private BigInteger dId;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "L_ID")
    private BigInteger lId;
    //... constructors, getters and setters
}
```

When I use the source code above as is, I get:

> 12:56:04,021 WARNING [org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain]
>   (default task-83) Application
>   {http://services.webservices.*****.******.com/}ObjectManagerService#{http://services.webservices.*****.******.com/}getAllObjects
>   has thrown exception, unwinding now: org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   org.hibernate.TypeMismatchException: Provided id of the wrong type for
>   class com.******.*****.**.********.Two. Expected: class
>   com.******.*****.**.********.TwoPK, got class
>   com.******.*****.**.********.OnePK    at
>   org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.createFault(AbstractInvoker.java:162)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.jaxws.AbstractJAXWSMethodInvoker.createFault(AbstractJAXWSMethodInvoker.java:267)
>     at

When I use the same class (OnePK) as the primary key of both classes (One and Two), I get:

> 11:44:35,735 WARNING [org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain]
>   (default task-83) Interceptor for
>   {http://services.webservices.*****.******.com/}ObjectManagerService#{http://services.webservices.*****.******.com/}getAllObjects
>   has thrown exception, unwinding now: org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault:
>   Marshalling Error: A cycle is detected in the object graph. This will
>   cause infinitely deep XML : One[ onePK=OnePK[ dId=3151, lId=426 ] ] ->
>   Two[ twoPK=OnePK[ dId=3151, lId=426 ] ] -> One[ onePK=OnePK[ dId=3151,
>   lId=426 ] ]   at
>   org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.marshall(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:266)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.jaxb.io.DataWriterImpl.write(DataWriterImpl.java:238)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AbstractOutDatabindingInterceptor.writeParts(AbstractOutDatabindingInterceptor.java:118)
>     at

Using @PrimaryKeyJoinColumns didn't help, I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10805591/458157) and [this tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-one-to-one-relationship-example-annotation/), I got the same error messages. Using @MapsId didn't help, I got "org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not prepare statement". Maybe the root cause is [this unfixed bug of Hibernate](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-3993). The only workaround that I've found consists in removing the very first occurrence of @OneToOne and the field "two" in the class "One" but the instance of Two contained by an instance of One no longer gets deleted when I delete this instance of One, that's why I used CascadeType.ALL.

This JPA source code is auto-generated by Netbeans 8. I'm a bit out of options. Is there a way of making it work correctly? Is it really a limitation of Hibernate? Is there another implementation of JPA handling this case correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, I increased the TTL connection timeout in Oracle UCP by calling [this method](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e12826/oracle/ucp/jdbc/PoolDataSource.html#setTimeToLiveConnectionTimeout_int_) in order to get rid of the `GenericJDBCException`. Some requests were taking too much time to execute whereas the time allowed to keep a connection in use was too low.

Secondly, I used the same class named OnePK as the primary key of both classes One and Two.

Thirdly, I added `@XmlTransient` into the class Two before the method getOne() in order to fix the cycle in the XML serialization.

Fourthly, I modified my managers so that they call Two.setOne(final One one) in order to expose complete objects (instances of Two) for the source code calling the persistence layer without using the web services.

At last, I fixed some similar cases but with simpler primary keys composed of only one column by using `@MapsId`.

Comment: Using the same id class `OnePK` as primary key for classes `One` and `Two` implies that both tables have the identifier column names.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem comes from the `name` attribute used in your `@JoinColumn` mapping, in your `Two` class, where the value used for `name` is the same as `referencedColumnName`.

In fact `Two` class already has `P_ID` and `L_ID` attributes embedded from its `TwoPk` class, so when you will use the same names `name = "P_ID"` and `name = "L_ID"`, you can't map both class because these attributes are already in this `Entity` so you should specify different names:

```
@JoinColumns({
    @JoinColumn(name = "OneP_ID", referencedColumnName = "P_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false),
    @JoinColumn(name = "OneL_ID", referencedColumnName = "L_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)})
@OneToOne(optional = false)
private One one;
```

**Note:**

If you are using two differents classes for PKs, why are you using the same attributes names in both classes, it would better if you identified them with differents names in `OnePk` and `TwoPk` as :

Respectively `oneDId` and `oneLId` in your `OnePk` class and `twoDId` and `twoLId` in your `TwoPk` class, this will make things better and easier to read, to identify and to map.

Comment: Actually, I cannot change those names in the Java source code as I'm not allowed to change them in the SQL tables, they have to match :s

Comment: Well, you can give them differents names in Java and use the same name in the `@Column` annotation, but anyway this is not the point here, have changed the `@JoinColumns` configuration?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by having one side of the relation with `@OneToOne` and the second side of the relation as `@ManyToOne`. The IDE may warn about mapping incoherence, but it works.

Comment: Glad to know it works for you but it seems to be dirty, I don't exactly measure the consequences.